# <Response [503]> при попытке получить данный с сайта

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, web-scraping

Всем привет, набросал простую программу, которая собирает данные о товарах в одном интернет магазине. Когда запускаю все отлично, но при частом запуске вылетает
. Поглядев в интернете, понял ,что это связано с частыми запросами на сервер, перезапустив роутер ,все сработало, но через некоторое время опять перестало. Возможно ли как-то эту проблему обходить на регулярной основе? Буду очень признателен.
Вот кусочек кода тестового файла:

```
def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(r)
    return r.text


def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    pages = soup.find("li", id="result_59")
    print(pages)
```

Comment: Ошибку 503 выдаёт этот самый «один интернет магазин», проблема на его стороне. Возможно, проблема вызвана тем, что ваш скрипт обращается к сайту слишком часто — нужно обращаться реже, а не роутеры перезапускать. А возможно, вы тут совсем ни при чём — это проблемы администраторов сайта, а не ваши

Comment: Попробуйте для начала при получении ошибки заменить user-agent, затем изменить прокси

Comment: Большое спасибо за наводки, буду разбираться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте такой способ.

```
from urllib.response import Request, urlopen

def get_html(url):
    req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    webpage = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf8')
    return webpage
```

Answer (score 0):

Совет от floydya навел на ,судя по всему, окончательное решение. У меня все заработало так:

```
import urllib.request
def get_html(url):
r = urllib.request.Request(url,
                           data = None,
                           headers=
                               {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
                           )
f = urllib.request.urlopen(r)
return f.read().decode("utf-8")
```